# Improving pagination

Tags: feature-request, pagination

Here's a trivial observation about pagination (specifically in StackOverflow, but I guess it applies throughout StackExchange)...

Presently, pagination at the bottom of the page looks something like this:

```
prev  1 ...  7  8  9 10 11 ... 53 next
                   -
```

I think it would be more convenient it if went something more like this...

```
prev  1 ...  8  9 10 ... 22 ... 53 next
                -
```

and then, if 22 was selected

```
prev  1 ...  11 ... 21 22 23 ... 38 ... 53 next
```

That said, I appreciate that people have probably got more useful things to attend to - as, I suppose, have I - I'll get my coat.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but it isn't clear to me **how* this is supposed to improve pagination. Do you usually jump into a page in the middle?

Comment: ... And why 22 and 38? They're not even a set distance away from the current page with 22 being 13 pages away and 38 being 16 pages away... it's completely random.

Comment: The actual numbers aren't relevant. It's the principle of having an option other than 'next page' and 'end'

Answer (score 2):

I wonder which navigation path you are following. It does seem a nice addition, but only if you are looking for a specific page. Did you ever do that? Why?

Personally I don't think I would use this much, I usually go left-to-right or to the end immediately and then right-to-left. I never actually wanted to go half-way.

Comment: I was idly looking for answers that had received a certain number of upvotes (2 to be precise), so I had to wade through 1s and 0s first. I know, first world problems, right?

Comment: Why didn't you search for [`score:2..2`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A2..2+is%3Aq) then?

Comment: Because I'm a numpty :-$

Answer (score 2):

You can also switch to any page you like by messing with the URL.

> https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest

Change the 4 after "page" in the URL to any number you like to see whichever page you want.

So, for page 30:

> https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions?page=30&sort=newest

There's no need to change the UI to something random just for this rare use.