# For paginated results, add a way to type the page number to which to navigate

Tags: feature-request, search, sorting, navigation, pagination

I'd like to request a feature addition where navigating to the page of the result I desire to view (in any SE website) is able to be done by simply entering the page number of the results page you want to go to, in a small prompt that pops up when clicking the "..." button.

An example of what it may look like: [image]

This is from NarutoForums for anyone curious.

While it is true that one can navigate to any page they like by merely changing the `page=<page number>` part of the URL, I believe a feature such as this integrated into the site user interface itself makes it much more convenient for everyone, and not everyone may know this "URL trick" either (as I did not). It also reduces the risk of mistyping into the URL which is a lot more difficult to see than just the page number displayed at the bottom of a page.

Comment: Related: (2009) [Isn't it time to change the page advance system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3847/986753); (2009) [Page Navigation, goto page N, feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12330/986753); (2012) [Clicking the ellipsis between page numbers should prompt for a page number \[duplicate\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121949/986753); (2013) [Adding a button to improve navigation through the questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172246/986753); (2016) [Improving pagination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283137/986753)

Comment: (2023) [Add a "go to page" when looking through unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395252)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made a userscript called Better Paginator that adds this functionality. It replaces the ellipsis in the default paginator with a box where you can type in the page number you want to go to, and then if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will take you to that page number:

[image]

You'll need a userscript manager (I use Tampermonkey), and then you can install it by clicking on this install button:

<kbd>[Install](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/se-userscripts/raw/main/better-paginator/better-paginator.user.js)</kbd>

The source code is [on GitHub here](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/se-userscripts/blob/main/better-paginator/better-paginator.user.js).